# Best way to check version of dependent project

Tags: c#, version-control

I have two project A(application) and B(library) both in C# 3.5. A refers B. Now what I want is A should not build or crash at runtime unless it uses a certain version of B. Which is the best way to achieve this? Should I go for strong naming?

Project A will have continues changes made to it. However project B will be more or less static unless a major bug is found.

Answer (score 1):

[Use strong-named assemblies](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wd40t7ad(VS.71).aspx).  Can't link/compile without the proper version.